# How to properly express $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty}$ with sine and cosine

Tags: limits

Often, I'm asked to solve limits for expressions that contain sine or cosine. Limits for sine or cosine do not exist in $\infty$. But yet, limits with sine and cosine may have a solution:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+\sin(x)}{x+\cos(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\infty+???}{\infty+???} = 1$$

I wonder how should I properly write this and what is used instead of question marks. I felt like using $<-1,1>$ here, but that's a funny solution.

Comment: Divide top and bottom of your expression by $x$ and apply known limits and limit rules. (And don't treat "$\infty$" as if it were a number.)

Comment: Your procedure is incorrect: you cannot take limits of individual terms and combine them. Instead, think what happens when you plug in a large number for $x$, and then an even larger one.

Comment: @DavidMitra And what $\frac{sin(\infty)}{\infty}$ should be? It sounds like a $0$ to me. That would make my example $\frac{0}{0}$ then...

Comment: Ah damn, forgotten the $1$. So it's $\frac{1+0}{1+0}$. I get it now.

Comment: @TomášZato If you continue to think to $\sin(\infty)/\infty$ you'll never understand how it works. While something like $1/\infty$ can help intuition (but it's still risky), there's *no* way to give a sensible meaning to $\sin(\infty)$.

Comment: sometimes the sub of y=1/x help

Comment: If I understood well how it works, @egreg, I'd never post this question.